# Symfony2 DoctrineExtensions preSoftDelete event call, not saving custom data in database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

If I var_dump($object), the field status is updated in the object, but not saved in database.

Can you help me ?

```
<?php
namespace Acme\MyBundle\EventListener;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class SoftDeleteListener {

    public function preSoftDelete(LifecycleEventArgs $args){

        $em = $args->getEntityManager();

        $object = $args->getEntity();

        //if entity has field "status"
        if($em->getClassMetadata(get_class($object))->hasField('status')){
            //set the status with string "deleted"
            $object->setStatus('deleted');
        }

    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should persist your object and notify the UoW that you have made some changes. You can achieve that adding this in your condition:

```
 $em->persist($object);
 $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($object));
 $em->getUnitOfWork()->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $object);
```